# How do I create nested list items within a dynamically created list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

newbie here. I need a little help,

I have an empty ul that gets list items added to it when the user fills out a form and clicks 'save'. I am trying to set it up so they can double click on the added list item, and add more information to that item through another form in a jQuery UI dialog window, and it will be saved in a nested list.

This app is a basic D&D initiative tracker, the DM can add players and their initiative, as well as the enemies, and it automatically sorts them from highest initiative to lowest. The nested lists will be for effects cast on the players/enemies.

Here is a jsfiddle of my code so far, I added in a list item so you can just double click that to see the modal without having to fill out the form: 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pix0id/6VeA5/1/)

This is the closest I've been able to get it. It adds the information to the dialog window, and not the list item. Everything else I've tried has just given me errors.

Here's the relevant code:

```
var conName
var duration
$('ul').on('dblclick', 'li', function(){

    $('#modal').dialog({
        title: 'TEST',
        buttons: [ { 
            text : 'save', 
            click: function() {
                conName = $('#con').val();
                duration = parseInt($('#dur').val()); 
                $(this).parent().append('<li>' + conName + ' ------ ' + duration + '</li>' );
}}]
    });
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
var conName
var duration
$('ul').on('dblclick', 'li', function(){
    _this = $(this);
    $('#modal').dialog({
        title: 'TEST',
        buttons: [ { 
            text : 'save', 
            click: function() {
                conName = $('#con').val();
                duration = parseInt($('#dur').val()); 
                _this.find('.subName').html(conName);
}}]
    });
```

[You can check it out at jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bcHTD/1/)

Comment: Hmm, not quite what I was looking for, I was able to get this solved elsewhere (About two minutes after posting this..) you can check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6VeA5/10/)